# .properties files in regular src folder okay?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I work on a Java project with a suggested structure (separate src folders for java files and resource files).

After moving the message / text related properties files to that folder, the externalize strings mechanism in Eclipse does not work as before.

Usually when hovering over the key string in a getString("") call, the tooltip showed the content of the properties file with the default locale. That has been extremely helpful for me personally. It seems as if that feature only works if the properties file is in the same source folder as the Java code that manages the BUNDLE_NAME stuff.

Can I make a strong case for moving the properties file back to the src-folder, or should they be kept separate from the java source files? Anything else that I can try to get the feature to work again with the new structure?

Comment: The resource folder, at least what should be made available statically from your source, should be a *source* folder.  If you do it that way, there should be no difference.  Both are compiled and thrown in the same jar file just the same.  The primary difference is organization.  However if you simply created a folder, it no longer gets the special treatment which items in the source folder have, and while you can still use it, it remains external to the jar.

Comment: did you search / ask (at Stack Overflow) whether Eclipse can be configured to pick properties from folder other than src? [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Primarily I wanted to know if it is generally acceptable to put .properties files in src folders, because they might be a special case. They are put into java src folders in many tutorials. I did search with the keywords "properties", "eclipse", "java", "src-folder" etc. before I asked the question and I did not find anything helpful. Adding the 2nd question (if anybody knows how to deal with the exact problem in Eclipse) was probably a mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you looked at the directory structure imposed by maven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, its not ok to put property files into the source directory.  Some build environments could get rather unhappy with such a structure.  While yes, it may work, and the source directory may be in the class path for you in Eclipse, the best option is to have the resources in a separate directory.

Think of the build process.  This is typically 'build all the files from the source directory and put the resulting class files in another directory (target, or dist)'.  When there are property files (and other resources) mixed in there, the build gets more complex having to select another set of files to get copied to the build directory.

A much easier approach is to have source in one spot and resources in another.  This is actually the preferred directory structure that [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) requires (with some directories left out):

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/main/webapp
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

This allows the tests (JUnit or TestNG) to be able to use a separate set of resources rather than the main resources and makes testing much easier.

Likewise, the webapp directory is handled specially when building a .war file.

Keeping the properties separate makes for an easier build process, a cleaner identification of the files that are needed to be part of the class path, and an easier test environment for overriding those files that are part of the main class path for testing.

Comment: I was not going to put all the configuration files in a src directory. But property files with messages and labels that the package makes no sense without, I still do not see a hard fact that makes it a bad idea. It should be put into the target directory. That is a feature in that case. The unit tests should also have access to those labels / messages. They are pretty much a part of the implementation ... I almost want them hardcoded ...

Comment: @Signature consider [test/resources/connection_config.properties](https://github.com/shagie/TestingWithHsqldb/blob/master/src/test/resources/connection_config.properties) which would be found when doing tests (but not bundled in the war) which overrides [main/resources/connection_config.properties](https://github.com/shagie/TestingWithHsqldb/blob/master/src/main/resources/connection_config.properties).  However, in that project, there's only one log4j in the main and that is used for both.  The thing is by having these resources in a separate spot, the class path can be modified accordingly.

Comment: Okay, so I guess having them in the resources folder and saying goodbye to all convenience is the way to go. I really hate proprietary solutions. Well, it is not the first annoyance I have to deal with. I'm starting to get used to those ;-(

Comment: @Signature I am curious about the nature of the convince and annoyance you are facing.  Personally, I find it just the opposite.  If you could stop by [chat] (the whiteboard), I like to know more about the issues you are facing.

Comment: As a non-native speaker I am not a fan of real-time communication ;-) ... the worst 2 things have been mentioned. 1.) With the Eclipse approach static analysis of the string externalization is possible. I learned that it is not possible to set something similar up in an IDE independent way. 2.) The other IDEs might be able to deal with the Eclipse NLS comments, so I we could probably allow the use of the mechanism, but with the resource folder excluded from the classpath the content of the property files is not shown where the keys are used - and one can not jump to the file either.

Comment: I think that almost _none_ of the claims made by this answer stands.  I cannot prove a negative, so I cannot say that there exists no build environment nor IDE that has a problem with this, but I am using Maven + IntelliJ IDEA and I am placing resources in the same folders as source files, and I have no problem whatsoever.  Specifically, Maven not only has no problem with this, but it actually offers notation for explicitly supporting it, see <resources><resource><directory> and <includes> / <excludes> <filtering> and <targetPath>.

Comment: Maven's preferred structure is preferred ***if*** you have to have resource folders, but you don't have to have them. Also, where you place your production and test resources has nothing to do with your ability nor your ease in performing your tests.  The only difference between the two approaches is that when the resource files are in the same folders as source files, they end up in the classpath, while when they are under a separate resource folder, they are not in the classpath.  That was never a problem for me, and I cannot see why it should be a problem to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Don't let your tools (IDEs, frameworks, build tools, etc) dictate how you organise your code.  Don't put your properties files where eclipse wants them and don't put them where your packaging tool would like them.

Organise your code such that it is obvious what your application does and so that code and resources are as close to the things they depend on as possible. If you want to change feature foo it you should be able to find it and all of its dependencies close together not intermingled with bar. You shouldn't have to search or rely on your ide to find what you're looking for.

If your tools don't support this approach then change your tools.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we will have to rethink the whole I18n approach. I thought the NLS approach that Eclipse uses was based on an official Java specification. Today I Learned that that was too optimistic. Every stupid tool uses its own messed up unportable solutions for those common problems (yeah, I'm annoyed). Problem is, I do not know what to replace the Eclipse solution with ... is seems as if there is no mechanism that detects unexternalized strings and another way to see values from property files.